# How to add menu items separators which work as expected on OSX?

Tags: delphi, menuitem, separator, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

On **Windows** platform, with the **VCL**, when we want to add a **separator** in a menu, we add a `TMenuItem` with a `Caption := '-'`;

With **FireMonkey**, we add a `TMenuItem` with a `Text := '-'`;

It works as expected on Windows platform, the item with the Text='-' is displayed as a separator.

But, when I run the same application on **OSX**, I have the minus sign visible...

I haven't found any property on the `TMenuItem` to specify it is a **separator**...

I have tried with a `TMainMenu` and a `TMenuBar` (`UseOSMenu := True|False;`) and I still have this issue.

**Any idea to create a real separator?** (otherwise, I will check the OS and remove it if OSX...)

Comment: My guess is you should report this in QualityCentral.  Remember that firemonkey 1.0 is a first release, and so there are things like this that are probably not yet implement on FMX-Mac.

Comment: This is what I think too... As this is a v1, this is why I haven't asked for the accelerator because I think this is not implemented at all...

Comment: @Warren P: Here we go... [bug reported](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=99182)

Comment: Oh come on, surely they have implemented separators and accelerators.

Comment: @David: If you find the accelerators, let me know ;o)

Comment: If they aren't there I'll revise my verdict down from preview release to alpha release.

Comment: @David Heffernan: As far as I know the concept of accelerators does not exist in OSX (Carbon), it only has keyboard (combo) shortcuts. Sounds to me like a "cross-platform first, optimize per platform later" approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in FireMonkey. I am sure they will solve it. But meanwhile you can use the below code. Call the procedure FixSeparatorItemsForMac in the OnActivate event of your main form.

Dont forget mac specific files in the uses list.

```
uses
...
  {$IFDEF MACOS}
  ,Macapi.ObjectiveC,MacApi.AppKit,MacApi.Foundation,FMX.Platform.Mac
  {$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF MACOS}

Procedure FixSeparatorItemsForMenuItem(MenuItem:NSMenuItem);
var i:Integer;
    subItem:NSMenuItem;
begin
  if (MenuItem.hasSubmenu = false) then exit;
  for i := 0 to MenuItem.submenu.itemArray.count -1 do
  begin
    subItem := MenuItem.submenu.itemAtIndex(i);
    if (subItem.title.isEqualToString(NSSTR('-'))= true) then
    begin
      MenuItem.submenu.removeItemAtIndex(i);
      MenuItem.submenu.insertItem(TNSMenuItem.Wrap(TNSMenuItem.OCClass.separatorItem),i);
    end else begin
      FixSeparatorItemsForMenuItem(subItem);
    end;
  end;
end;

Procedure FixSeparatorItemsForMac;
var NSApp:NSApplication;
    MainMenu:NSMenu;
    AppItem: NSMenuItem;
    i: Integer;
begin
  NSApp := TNSApplication.Wrap(TNSApplication.OCClass.sharedApplication);
  MainMenu := NSApp.mainMenu;
  if (MainMenu <> nil) then
  begin
    for i := 0 to MainMenu.itemArray.count -1 do
    begin
      AppItem := mainMenu.itemAtIndex(i);
      FixSeparatorItemsForMenuItem(AppItem);
    end;

  end;
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks! Do you know how to add items in the application menu  under Mac... the one with the Quit... (I can create another question if needed...)

Comment: Yes Whiler. You can create a question about menu items in Firemonkey. But notfiy me when you post it.

Comment: [Done ;o)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632838/how-to-create-subitems-menus-under-the-application-name-on-osx)

Comment: This was fixed in Delphi XE2 Update 2.

Answer (score 0):

I never programmed for the Mac, and I don't eveb have a Mac but out of curiosity I found some Apple Documentation about it.

The Menu Separator item is a disabled blank menu item, maybe you can fake with that:

> separatorItem
>
> Returns a menu item that is used to separate logical groups of menu
>   commands.
>   + (NSMenuItem *)separatorItem Return Value
>
> A menu item that is used to separate logical groups of menu commands.
>
> Discussion
>
> This menu item is disabled. The default separator item is blank space.

(From: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSMenuItem)

Comment: You are talking about Cocoa. The question is about FireMonkey.

Comment: Yes I know, I'm talking about how it's implemented natively by Cocoa. Reading that documentation seems to be safe to add a blank disabled item in Firemonkey

Comment: FireMonkey does not use Cocoa. They are unrelated.

Comment: Just in case... I give a try... but, as expected, it just generates an empty item... not a separator...

Comment: FireMonkey uses the native OS menus, though, @David.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the facilities to test this, but it's worth a try.

By default, FireMonkey creates it's own fully styled menus, but set the TMenuBar.UseOSMenu property to true and it uses OS calls to create the menus.

You can then combine this with the advice for creating Cocoa menus already discussed.

From http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FireMonkey_Application_Design#Menus :

"Setting the TMenuBar.UseOSMenu property to True causes FireMonkey to create the menu tree with OS calls, resulting in a native menu. On Windows, this menu is at the top of the parent form, and displayed using the current Appearance theme. On Mac OS X, the menu is displayed in the global menu bar on top of the main screen whenever the application has focus."

Comment: Like I said, I already tested it with the different objects and I alse tried with the Cocoa spec (__I have tried with a TMainMenu and a TMenuBar UseOSMenu := True|False;) and I still have this issue.__) It just generates an empty item... not a separator... I confirm, it is displayed on the global menu (for TMainMenu **and** 'TMenuBar with UseOSMenu=true'