# How to create subitems menus under the application name on OSX?

Tags: macos, delphi, menuitem, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

How to add TMenuItem under **Project1** and above *Quit* on the screenshot below?

[image]

I have created a TMenuBar with property UseOSMenu checked.
The first TMenuItem I added is the second one in the main bar...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by assigning a TMenuBar of IItemsContainer implementing class to the Application.ApplicationMenuItems property.

Example:

If there was a menu bar component on the form called MenuBar1, then you would just call the following in your forms constructor (or OnCreate).

`Application.ApplicationMenuItems := Menubar1;`

You can then have a second TMenuBar component to define the other menu items.

I'd point you to the wiki topic on the ApplicationMenuItems property, but it has no additional help...

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/FMX.Forms.TApplication.ApplicationMenuItems

Comment: In XE7 this property doesn't exist, nor does anything like it on `TApplication`. Perhaps it was moved elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I have created a unit to try to manage what I would like...
With it, I can use a specific TMenuItem... and **move** its subitems to the application submenu... (I still don't know how to add one from scratch...)

I also use the answer from [Mehmed Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505581/how-to-add-menu-items-separators-which-work-as-expected-on-osx/7628834#7628834) to manage the separators...

```
unit uMenu;

interface

uses
FMX.Dialogs, System.SysUtils,
  FMX.Menus
{$IFDEF MACOS}
  ,Macapi.ObjectiveC,MacApi.AppKit,MacApi.Foundation,FMX.Platform.Mac
{$ENDIF}
  ;

  type
    ManageMenu = class
  private
{$IFDEF MACOS}
    class procedure FixSeparatorItemsForMenuItem (MenuItem: NSMenuItem);
    class procedure MoveItemsToMacApplicationMenu(source, target: NSMenuItem); overload;
    class procedure MoveItemsToMacApplicationMenu(index: Integer);             overload;
{$ENDIF}
  public
    class procedure FixSeparatorItemsForMac;
    class procedure MoveItemsToMacApplicationMenu(index: Integer; menu: TMainMenu); overload;
    class procedure MoveItemsToMacApplicationMenu(index: Integer; menu: TMenuBar);  overload;
  end;

implementation

{ ManageMenu }

{$IFDEF MACOS}
class procedure ManageMenu.FixSeparatorItemsForMenuItem(MenuItem:NSMenuItem);
var
  i      : Integer;
  subItem: NSMenuItem;
begin
  if (MenuItem.hasSubmenu = False) then exit;

  for i := 0 to Pred(MenuItem.submenu.itemArray.count) do
  begin
    subItem := MenuItem.submenu.itemAtIndex(i);
    if (subItem.title.isEqualToString(NSSTR('-'))= True) then
    begin
      MenuItem.submenu.removeItemAtIndex(i);
      MenuItem.submenu.insertItem(TNSMenuItem.Wrap(TNSMenuItem.OCClass.separatorItem), i);
    end
    else
    begin
      FixSeparatorItemsForMenuItem(subItem);
    end;
  end;
end;
{$ENDIF}

class procedure ManageMenu.FixSeparatorItemsForMac;
{$IFDEF MACOS}
var
  NSApp   : NSApplication;
  MainMenu: NSMenu;
  AppItem : NSMenuItem;
  i       : Integer;
{$ENDIF}
begin
{$IFDEF MACOS}
  NSApp    := TNSApplication.Wrap(TNSApplication.OCClass.sharedApplication);
  MainMenu := NSApp.mainMenu;
  if (MainMenu <> nil) then
  begin
    for i := 0 to Pred(MainMenu.itemArray.Count) do
    begin
      AppItem := mainMenu.itemAtIndex(i);
      FixSeparatorItemsForMenuItem(AppItem);
    end;
  end;
{$ENDIF}
end;

{$IFDEF MACOS}
class procedure ManageMenu.MoveItemsToMacApplicationMenu(source, target: NSMenuItem);
var
  iLoop, iMax: Integer;
  subItem    : NSMenuItem;
begin
  if (source.hasSubmenu = False) then exit;

  iMax := Pred(source.submenu.itemArray.count);
  for iLoop := iMax downto 0 do
  begin
    subItem := source.submenu.itemAtIndex(iLoop);
    source.submenu.removeItemAtIndex(iLoop);
    target.submenu.insertItem(subItem, 0);
  end;
  // Hide the parent
  source.setHidden(True);
end;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF MACOS}
class procedure ManageMenu.MoveItemsToMacApplicationMenu(index: Integer);
var
  NSApp   : NSApplication;
  MainMenu: NSMenu;
  source  : NSMenuItem;
  target  : NSMenuItem;
begin
  NSApp    := TNSApplication.Wrap(TNSApplication.OCClass.sharedApplication);
  MainMenu := NSApp.mainMenu;
  if (MainMenu <> nil) then
  begin
    begin
      if (MainMenu.itemArray.count > 1) then
      begin
        source := mainMenu.itemAtIndex(Succ(index));
        target := mainMenu.itemAtIndex(0);
        MoveItemsToMacApplicationMenu(source, target);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
{$ENDIF}

class procedure ManageMenu.MoveItemsToMacApplicationMenu(index: Integer; menu: TMainMenu);
begin
{$IFDEF MACOS}
  MoveItemsToMacApplicationMenu(index);
{$ELSE}
//  (menu.Children[Succ(index)] as TMenuItem).Visible := False;
//  menu.RemoveObject(...);
// ... I don't knwo how to remove items on Windows ;o(((
{$ENDIF}
end;

class procedure ManageMenu.MoveItemsToMacApplicationMenu(index: Integer; menu: TMenuBar);
begin
{$IFDEF MACOS}
  MoveItemsToMacApplicationMenu(index);
{$ELSE}
  if (menu.ChildrenCount > Succ(index)) and (menu.Children[Succ(index)] is TMenuItem) then
  begin
//  (menu.Children[Succ(index)] as TMenuItem).Visible := False;
//  menu.RemoveObject(...);
// ... I don't knwo how to remove items on Windows ;o(((

//    menu.BeginUpdate;
//    menu.RemoveObject((menu.Children[Succ(index)] as TMenuItem));
//    menu.RemoveFreeNotify((menu.Children[Succ(index)] as TMenuItem));
//    menu.DeleteChildren;
//    (menu.Children[Succ(index)] as TMenuItem).View.Visible := False;
//    .Free;
//    (menu.Children[Succ(index)] as TMenuItem).Destroy;
//    menu.EndUpdate;
  end;
{$ENDIF}
end;

end.
```

It works as expected and it is what I want on OSX...

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not bAlreadyActivated then
  begin
    bAlreadyActivated := True;
    ManageMenu.FixSeparatorItemsForMac;
    ManageMenu.MoveItemsToMacApplicationMenu(0, MainMenu1);
  end;
end;
```

but now, I have an issue on Windows because whatever I try, I still have the menu I added for Mac displayed under Windows... ;o(

Comment: An extra ifdef should take care of that

Comment: @Johan: around what? ;o( The only way I found is to create the menuitems only if it's on osx... but, that means to dynamically create them, in the source and not in the dfm... which is less user-friendly.... is it what you mean or do you have another idea?

Comment: My idea was to ifdef a separate source for OSX and Windows. two completely different trees. Note that changing the systemmenu in Windows is a very rare thing and not recommended at all, so normally you'd do that under the `file` menu.

Comment: hummm.. I see.. I can create 2 different datamodules.. one for each platform and use the good one with ifdef... good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of Delphi XE7, the `Application.ApplicationMenuItems` property no longer exists.

You now have to create a `TMainMenu` item to get the expected result, no need to assign it. Just drop a `TMainMenu` on to your main form and add your items, and they will appear in the OSX application menu.